# GA4 Add, edit, and delete Analytics users and user groups with API

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-analytics-4

I would like to manage my resource via script because I have a lot of users that need to access property differently in many accounts. I would like to do it with a Python script instead of manually on a web UI, but I cannot find any document or example of Add, edit, and delete Analytics users in GA4 (account and property) to solve my problem. I need right script of add, edit, delete.

I tried this code:

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests


KEY_FILE_PATH = './service-account-file.json'

# Scopes required by the API, including the scope for managing users
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users'
]

# Authenticate and construct service
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    KEY_FILE_PATH, scopes=SCOPES)

# Create a request object
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

# Use the request object to refresh the service account credentials
credentials.refresh(auth_req)

# Get the token
token = credentials.token

# Headers for API requests
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

def fetch_account_summaries():
    """Fetches account summaries and prints them."""
    url = 'https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/accountSummaries'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        summaries = response.json().get('accountSummaries', [])

        for account in summaries:
            account_id = account.get('name')
            account_name = account.get('displayName')
            print(f'Account ID: {account_id}, Account Name: {account_name}')

            properties = account.get('propertySummaries', [])
            for property in properties:
                property_id = property.get('property')
                property_name = property.get('displayName')
                print(f'  Property ID: {property_id}, Property Name: {property_name}')
    else:
        print("Error fetching account summaries:")
        print(response.text)

def add_user_to_property(target_property_name, user_email, user_role):
    """Adds a user to a Google Analytics property by property name."""
    # Fetch account summaries
    url = 'https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/accountSummaries'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    property_resource_name = None  # Corrected variable name for clarity

    if response.status_code == 200:
        summaries = response.json().get('accountSummaries', [])

        for account in summaries:
            properties = account.get('propertySummaries', [])
            for property in properties:
                if property.get('displayName') == target_property_name:
                    # Directly use the property's name which includes the 'properties/' prefix
                    property_resource_name = property.get('property')
                    break
            if property_resource_name:
                break

        if property_resource_name:
            # Correctly constructed URL for adding a user to a property
            add_user_url = f"https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/{property_resource_name}/userLinks"
            user_data = {
                "emailAddress": user_email,
                "directRoles": [user_role]
            }
            response = requests.post(add_user_url, headers=headers, json=user_data)

            if response.status_code in [200, 201]:
                print(f"User {user_email} added successfully to property {target_property_name}.")
                return True
            else:
                print("Failed to add user:")
                print(response.text)
                return False
        else:
            print(f"Property named '{target_property_name}' not found.")
            return False
    else:
        print("Error fetching account summaries:")
        print(response.text)
        return False


# Example usage
fetch_account_summaries()
# Example call to add a user to a property
property_name = "example.com"
user_email = "example@hotmail.com"
role="roles/editor"
add_user_to_property(property_name,user_email, role)
```

After running it seem like my API is wrong because request cannot be found on server.
Here is a part of an API that had been called:

```
"https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1beta/{property_resource_name}/userLinks"
```

This is error I got on the terminal:

```
Failed to add user:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1beta/properties/xxxxxxx/userLinks</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: I only see the alpha version has the feature you want in the document? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accounts.userLinks/create Can you share the doc you are referring to?